# How do I call static members of a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, static-methods

If I have:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
 static void f()
 {
  // not using template parameter T
 }
};
```

In this case `A<int>::f()` is same as `A<double>::f()`, but I don't want call `A::f()` via the template parameter. Is there a syntax that allows calling of `f()` but doesn't require the template parameter?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know that `A<T>::f()` doesn't use type parameter `T`.  So as it is, you must give the compiler a type any time you use `f`.

But when I'm designing a template class and I notice some members/methods don't depend on template parameters, I'll often move those up to a non-template base class.

```
class A_Base {
public:
  static void f();
};

template <class T> class A : public A_Base {
  // ...
};
```

Now `A_Base::f()`, `A<int>::f()`, and `A<double>::f()` really are all the same thing.

Comment: +1 for neat workaround. Though the compiler should be able to know if it uses the parameter T -- if there aren't any instances of the identifier T in the code then it's certainly not being used.

Comment: @Billy: But if the class is part of a public library, then introducing usage of the `T` parameter would cause an ABI-breaking change, since `A::f()` would no longer be valid.  The introduction of content into functions should *never, ever* break ABI, only changes in the function definition.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Yes, except when `f()` calls some `A<T>::g()` which does depend on `T`. However, since the general rule is that anything regarding use of an identifier should depend on its declaration only, the language doesn't equate `f<T>()` with `f()` even though `T` is not used in the body of `f<T>`.

Comment: +1 for class structure. Now code of f() won't be copied to all template specializations.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `private` inheritance here?

Comment: No, we want members of `A_Base` to be publicly accessible in the derived classes.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no syntax for specifying that. There's little reason to make `f` a static method anyway. Make it a free function instead. If you must make it a static method for some reason, implement it in terms of a free function and merely call it.
2. Many compilers will probably do this for you automatically.

Comment: I can't use free static function, because this is not my code I'm just using already written API.
Thanks a lot for answer :)

Comment: @Mihran: Huh? How can an API care about a static method? *sigh* (BILL SMASH STRANGE API! :) )

Answer (score 1):

No -- if you don't want to use a template argument, don't declare the class with a template parameter.  If you need the template argument for other members of the class, but don't need it in `f`, then move `f` out of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  Give it an alias by assigning it to a function pointer.

Comment: Of course, you'll still need to "use" a specific type to initialize that pointer, like `typedef void (*func_ptr)(); func_ptr A_f = &A<int>::f;`

Answer (score 0):

No, actually `A<int>::f()` is not the same of `A<any_other_type>::f()`. They are really different. If you want `f()` to be really independent of the parameter, you can make the template class `A` to inherit from another class (called sometimes a trait) that offers `f()` as a static member function:

```
struct X
{
  static void f() { ...}
};

template <typename T>
struct A : X
{
  ...
```

Then, you can call either `A<type>::f()` or `X::f()`.

Answer (score 0):

A cludgy work around (if you don't want to use inheritance and you don't want to make it a non-member function), you could specify a default type for your class:

```
template <class T = bool>
class A
{
  public:
   static void f() { cout << "f()" <<  endl; }
};

int main(void)
{
  A<>::f();
  return 0;
}
```

NOTE: this method however is **not the same as**, `A<int>::f()` or `A<long>::f()` etc. but if you have no type dependency in the function - then the above could work...

Answer (score 0):

Each class template instantiation has its own copy of any static data members. The static declaration can be of template argument type or of any defined type.

You must separately define static members. The following example demonstrates this:

```
template <class T> class K
{
public:
     static T x;
};
template <class T> T K<T> ::x;

int main()
{
    K<int>::x = 0;
}
```

The statement template T K::x defines the static member of class K, while the statement in the main() function assigns a value to the data member for K .